# Image not delete in cpanel

Tags: php, yii, cpanel

I delete a folder in cpanel it contain some image  and when I refresh my page I still see the same image it dose not exist at all I check the address it same what should I do ??

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your browser has cached the path. 
In this case you can clear the cache.

[Clear Cache](https://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/)

Comment: I checked it's not that